# Dynamic nature of python

Tags: python

I am a newbie to programmimg and python.
When I do:

```
 j = 100
 k = 200
 l = j + k
 l
 300
```

Now, if I change the value of J, I expect the output of 'l' to be different. Why is the output same and how can I make it change.

```
 j = 250
 l
 300
```

Comment: " I expect the output of 'l' to be different".  Really?  Why?  Please explain what you expected and why.

Comment: Python is not a spreadsheet :-)

Comment: However, if you do want this behavior, you can take a look at the sympy (external) module for symbolic math.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not what "dynamic" means. Once a value is assigned to a variable, the variable retains that value until it is assigned a different value.

Dynamic languages are those whose variables can take on any type at runtime, and usually can even hold multiple values of different types over their lifespan:

```
a = 1
print a
a = "hello"
print a
```

That said, you *can* achieve something similar to what you expected:

```
>>> j = 100
>>> k = 200
>>> l = lambda: j + k
>>> l()
300
>>> j = 250
>>> l()
450
```

Answer (score 6):

When the line

```
l = j + k
```

is exceuted, Python does roughly the following:

1. Load the objects currently bound to the names `j` and `k`.  Here, this will be the integers `100` and `200`.
2. Perform the addition.  This will create a new `int` object with the value `300`.
3. Bind the name `l` to the resulting object.

As you can see, `l` is just bound to an integer that doesn't "know" any more where it came from.

Answer (score 3):

In your code, `l = j + k` simply evaluates `j + k`, which results in an integer value of `300`. Then the name `l` is bound to that `int` object of value `300`.

The addition is evaluated once and once only. If you want a new addition to be performed then you will have to explicitly invoke it one way or another.

Answer (score 1):

*Structure and Intepretation of Programming* (http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-10.html#%_sec_1.1.2) has a really good section on this.

When you use expressions like j = 100 or k = 200, you are basically giving a new 'name' to the value.  This is an abstraction that you're making so that finding this number is easier later on.  When you assign a value to a variable, the interpreter:

1. Figures out (recursively) what is on the right side of the expression
2. Resolves that to a value (or string, or int, etc.)
3. Gives that value the 'name' that you are assigning it.

So in the case of l = j + k, the interpreter computes the value of j + k, then gives that value the name 'l'.  l has no sense of where it came from, it's just pointing at whatever that value we just computed was.

What you're looking for is *lambda*.  Lambda creates a *procedure* that is carried out every time you call it.

So you can create a procedure (function):

l = lambda j,k: j + k

where i and j are the arguments of the procedure.  Every time you call the procedure, it looks at the inputs you've given it (this particular case has i and j as inputs) and then follows through with the procedure.  Another potential candidate is:

l = lambda: j + k

this procedure takes no inputs, but every time it is called it looks up whatever value the variables j and k have been assigned, and then computes them.

The concept of variables vs. procedures vs. functions can be very confusing to the beginner programmer; this is a great question and I hope this answer was helpful :)

-Nathan Lachenmyer

Answer (score 0):

```
j = 100
k = 200
l = j + k
```

- j is a pointer to the memory holding 100
- k is a pointer to the memory holding 200
- l is a pointer to the memory holding 300

l is not a pointer to the unexcuted function of j + k as i think you were expecting.

changing j is not going to change the fact that l is pointing to 300.